# Could not find or load main class when running jar built with gradle

Tags: java, jar

I've been trying to solve this for hours now following advice from other questions but still haven't made any progress. Perhaps there's something I'm overlooking.

Here's the situation:
I'm building with gradle

**build.gradle**

```
{
...
jar {
    baseName = 'knn-poker-hand'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'mr.Driver'
    }
...
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
package mr;
import ...
public class Driver
{
  public Driver() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  { ... }
```

**project structure**

```
knn-poker
|-src
| |-mr
| | |-Driver.java
| | |-Map.java
| | |-Reduce.java
|-gradle
|-build.gradle
|-gradlew
|-gradlew.bat
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mr.Driver
<NEWLINE>
<NEWLINE>
```

When I run ./gradlew build, it appears to build successfully and outputs to build > libs > knn-poker-hand-0.1.0.jar

Now, when I run `java -jar knn-poker-hand-0.1.0.jar`, I get a `Error: Could not find or load main class mr.Driver`

I've ensured my project is using the correct jdk (jdk.1.8.0_121) and is set on the path as a system variable (windows) as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121.

I'm not sure what else to do and keep running into dead ends :(

Comment: did you open the jar? Is it inside it?

Comment: it looks like the classes are not in there, I suppose this is due to me not using src/main/java as the structure?

Comment: Probably. Move them and it will likely work

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm a dummy, i did not use a package structure with src/main/java and that seemed to be the problem. it is working now